# Video with blob URL

Tags: google-chrome, video, browser, safari, blob

On Chrome, I'm able to use `src` with a blob url directly on the `<video>` tag, however it fails on Safari without errors. Oddly, [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/unRob/3bd07a012597aa959c92) does work for me.

On Safari, I'm able to use `src` with the *same* blob url on the `<source>` tag inside a `<video>` tag, however it fails on Chrome without errors!

Are there any caveats to using blob URLs for videos with these browsers? Anything this behavior implies?

### Extra details

#### Chrome, src directly on video element

Works

```html
<video src="blob:https://localhost:8080/1b527b2c-9f5f-4525-b0a5-c547263dfdbd" controls="" autoplay=""></video>
```

#### Safari, src directly on video element

Doesn't work

```html
<video src="blob:https://localhost:8080/756c6e0c-b1f2-4d8d-a348-5cf26fa1fb1c" controls="" autoplay=""></video>
```

#### Chrome, src on source element

Doesn't work

```html
<video controls="" autoplay=""><source type="video/mp4" src="blob:https://localhost:8080/f8a3a890-e150-48bb-81e3-7d3ff6771e84"></video>
```

#### Safari, src on source element

Works

```html
<video controls="" autoplay=""><source type="video/mp4" src="blob:https://localhost:8080/30b3e571-4240-4c47-af73-0b6604672fd1"></video>
```

Comment: hi @Shruggie, I am not able to use blob URL as src on video element on safari.However <source> element with src also doesn't working. what was your final solution on your issue?

Comment: Still no solution here. Lmk if you figure it out @pgcan!

Comment: couldn't find a solution. I check the browser in my code and set the src or <source> in video element.